# How do I resolve a dlopen error on foundation in Xcode 14.1?

Tags: python, xcode, kivy, foundation, dlopen

I am working on a kivy/python app in xcode. The simulator works fine but I get this weird error when I do run it. Furthermore, when I distribute the app to Appstore Connect and run it on testflight, the app wont even open. Here is the output of the error:

```
Got dlopen error on Foundation: dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/rip-rope-cfmmhpjupboxclftgokyxzvlhdgs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (errno=2), '/Users/macbook/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (errno=2), '/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/Users/macbook/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (errno=2), '/Users/macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/rip-rope-cfmmhpjupboxclftgokyxzvlhdgs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation' (errno=2), '/Users/macbook/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation' (errno=2), '/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/Users/macbook/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation' (errno=2)
Got fallback dlopen error on Foundation: dlopen(/Groups/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/rip-rope-cfmmhpjupboxclftgokyxzvlhdgs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (errno=2), '/Users/macbook/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Groups/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (errno=2), '/Groups/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (errno=2), '/Users/macbook/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation' (errno=2)
```

I've tried cleaning the project, re-building the project, messing around with the settings, setting the foundation framework to optioinal, you name it. Any help is great.